# In Vim, can I "stream" the output of e.g. "w ! ruby" into a buffer, line by line as they're output?

Tags: vim

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
redir => m
  silent w ! ruby
redir END
new
put=m
```

It executes the contents of the current buffer as Ruby code and puts the output in a new buffer.

But if the Ruby code I run is something like

```
puts "start"
sleep 10
puts "end"
```

then I will see no output for 10 seconds, then both "start" and "end" all at once.

Is there instead some way to "stream" the output to a buffer, line by line as it appears? So that I would see "start", then 10 seconds later I would see "end"? Similar to what happens if I just do

```
w ! ruby
```

and look at the output under the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Vim does not really expose primitives for this kind of I/O, but you can do it from one of the embedded language interfaces.

Here's a sketch using Python and [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) (Ruby would look similar; see [if_ruby](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_ruby.html)):

```
python << EOF
import vim
import subprocess

def output_lines_to_buffer(cmd):
    """
    Append the given shell command's output linewise to the current buffer.
    """
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, ''):
        vim.current.buffer.append(line)
        vim.command('redraw')
EOF
```

To use:

```
:python output_lines_to_buffer('my command')
```

This will simply append each line of output to the end of the current buffer, as `my command` emits it. You can extend it fairly straightforwardly to support input and output ranges and so on, depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

So one possible solution (hopefully not the best one) is to write to a file on disk, open that file in a buffer and do `:setlocal autoread` so the file autoupdates when it changes.

This autoupdating seems pretty rough, though. [Tail Bundle.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1714) seems to improve a little on it.

Hoping for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `tee` or `:make`, which uses tee.

```
let fname = tempname()
exec "w ! ruby 2>&1 | tee ".fname
exec "new ".fname
```

Edit: seems like you're on Linux, or an operating system that creates 4K buffers between pipelined processes.  To work around this, install `expect` (`sudo apt-get install expect-dev`) and use the `unbuffer` command to allow streaming on a line-by-line basis (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000674/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe).

```
let fname = tempname()
exec "! unbuffer ruby % 2>&1 | tee ".fname
exec "new ".fname
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, from what I can tell, it won't stream the output. Getting the output into a buffer is a solved problem - what I'm trying to figure out is a good way of having it output *incrementally*.

Comment: Ah, interesting. The first solution works for me on AIX. I was able to reproduce your observations on Linux, within vim and at the command-line, so I figure the buffering is occurring at the OS.  Updated the answer with a solution for Linux.  Hopefully that works for you!